# NDVI image processing

Tags: remote-sensing, ndvi, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, rasterio

I am trying to get a NDVI image from an RGB + NIR image captured by a modified Cannon S110 camera bought from Event38 along with a 3DR Iris+ drone [link](https://event38.com/product/iris-precision-mapping-package/)

The image captured with the camera looks like this
[image: Image captured with modified camera]

I have previously experimented with python and rasterio and successfully calculated an NDVI image from 2 images (one RGB and one NIR).

Researching around the internet I have found this to be achievable from one image. However I haven't found any image manipulation library to be helpful.

Can someone with more experience in this offer any guidance? Any programming language is welcome.

Comment: You'll need the red band and the nIR band. You can use scikit image, opencv, pillow... for this type of analysis. This may help: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/tutorial.html#processing-individual-bands\

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](http://geoinformaticstutorial.blogspot.co.at/2012/09/reading-raster-data-with-python-and-gdal.html) might be interesting for you.

You can access the indivudal bands (you need red and NIR) and calculate the NDVI from that.